# While building Angular project into production mode, I'm getting this error: Property 'activitydashboard' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, router

When I build my project using command `ng build --prod`, I am getting this error:

> Property 'activitydashboard' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'

I set value of router link and that is working perfectly on my localhost. So I am checking in production mode. But I am getting error.

On initial load, my image icon not coming, by navigation it is showing properly. By doing this **[routerLink]="activitydashboard"**, my image icon coming on initial load.

Below is my code:

```
<li id="activity" [routerLink]="activitydashboard" 
   [routerLinkActive]="['']" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''" #rla="routerLinkActive" class="Active pointer">
      <p class="link-items pointer"> 
      <img *ngIf="!rla.isActive" src="/assets/img/activity-blue-retina.png" class="links-img" alt=""> 
      <img *ngIf="rla.isActive" src="/assets/img/activity-white-retina.png" class="links-img" data-srcset="/assets/img/activity-white@2x.png,/assets/img/activity-white@3x.png" alt="">
      <span class="list-labels" >  Activity </span>
     </p>
</li>
```

When I build it in production mode, then it will show:

> ERROR : Property 'activitydashboard' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.**

It should also work properly in production mode as it is working in localhost. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use this `[routerLink]="['/activitydashboard']"`

Comment: I think in production build `routerLink` with `[]` consider `"activitydashboard"` as a variable declared in component, And failed to find in `.ts` file. Try `routerLink="activitydashboard"`.

Comment: just give like this   routerLink="activitydashboard"